# Expand multiple files without repeating long path

Tags: bash

sometimes i'm in a directory to which i want to copy two or three files from another directory.

So let's say i'm in an empty directory and the situation is like this:

```
user@hisBox:~/really/deep/directory/structure
$ pwd
/home/user/really/deep/directory/structure
```

Now i want to copy two files (a.txt and b.txt) from a distant directory that looks like this:

```
user@hisBox:~/really/deep/directory/structure
$ ls /home/user/really/deep2/bla/foo/textfolder
a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt
```

What i would like to type is something like this:

```
user@hisBox:~/really/deep/directory/structure
$ cp ../../../deep2/bla/foo/textfolder/{a.txt, b.txt} .
```

which should result in this

```
user@hisBox:~/really/deep/directory/structure
$ ls
a.txt b.txt
```

Is there a syntax available that allows me to do that in bash?

Comment: Almost exactly that actually, just drop the space after the comma. Also you can use `...../{a,b}.txt` since the `.txt` is common to both.

Comment: Ahh, i knew i was close... thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is (and you were pretty much already there):

```
cp ../../../deep2/bla/foo/textfolder/{a,b}.txt .
```

would copy the files `a.txt` and `b.txt` to your current directory. This is called [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

As gniourf_gniourf points out in the comments, you can also use [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) to do this:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp ../../../deep2/bla/foo/textfolder/@(a|b).txt .
```

The `@()` means that any file matching one of the pipe-separated options will be copied.

The difference between these two options is that the first expands to:

```
cp ../../../deep2/bla/foo/textfolder/a.txt ../../../deep2/bla/foo/textfolder/b.txt
```

*whether the two files exist or not*, whereas the second will only expand to files that it matches. Thanks again to gniourf_gniourf for the explanation.

Comment: Though it would be more semantically correct to use extglobs: `cp ../../../deep2/bla/foo/textfolder/@(a|b).txt .`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've edited my answer to include that option, thanks. I'm not sure I understand why it would be more semantically correct, though. Perhaps you could elaborate on that?

Comment: Because you're working on files that should exist, you really want a pattern expansion that matches existing files. A brace expansion always expands—whether the files exist or not—whereas a glob expands only expands according to existing files. That's why I'm (pedantically, I must admit) qualifying glob expansions as semantically correct.